# Magento 2 : Child theme not displaying Products

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

I've created child theme based on(Parent) default luma theme.

I had this setup with My Magento 2.2.3 with Sample Data.

Child theme is working fine, I enabled it. 
But problem i am getting is that after enabling child theme sample data is missing at frontend.

**But i can able to access products and categories by URL**

Does anybody gone through this issues ? Is there anything i am missing ??

Any help would be really helpful.

I've followed [This](http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-create-child-theme-in-magento2/) tutorial for creating child theme.

I also run `setup:upgrade` ,`setup:static-content:Deploy` ,`indexer:reindex` , `Cache:clean` but still not working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: DId you solve the issue? If you solved can you share how did you solve?

Comment: @Prabhu, Yes I've resolved but I forgot steps. Cant help you dude.